# How do we compute the $k$-th rational homology group of $\#^{\infty} S^{\infty}$?

Tags: homology-cohomology

> How do we compute the $k$-th rational homology group of the connected sum $\#^{\infty} S^{\infty}$, and hence the sequence of rational Betti numbers ${b_k\left(\#^{\infty} S^{\infty};\mathbb{Q}\right)}=\text{rk} H_k\left(\#^{\infty} S^{\infty};\mathbb{Q}\right)$? Since finding the homology of a sphere is trivial, I am essentially asking how to find the homology of a union of topological spaces?

**Context**: The space under consideration is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. In particular, if we consider an infinite-dimensional Hilbert manifold $M$, then we patch it via an atlas $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}$ for $A$ countable, but infinite and where $\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}$ is $S^{\infty}$,$\forall\alpha\in A$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by this union?  In what ambient space?

Comment: Embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. In particular, if we consider an infinite-dimensional manifold $M$, then we patch it via an atlas $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}$ for $A$ countable, but infinite and where $\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}$ is $S^{\infty},\forall\alpha\in A$. @EricWofsey

Comment: Every manifold is a union of contractible charts but most have interesting homology. You can say nothing if you don't know pairwise (triple, etc) intersections of your subsets.

Comment: @MikeMiller Couldn't we choose an "atlas" such that $\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}\cap\mathcal{U}_{\beta}=\emptyset$ for all $\alpha,\beta$ and then the homology would simply be $H_k\left(\sqcup_{\alpha\in A}\mathcal{U}_{\alpha};\mathbb{Q}\right)=\oplus_{\alpha\in A}H_k(\mathcal{U}_{\alpha};\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: If they pairwise intersect trivially that is a disjoint union.

Comment: @MikeMiller Please look at my idea that I added above.

Comment: The tangent bundle is not a disjoint union of charts.

Comment: Sorry, a mental lapse on my part. @MikeMiller

Comment: @MikeMiller I meant a connected sum.

Comment: For every $k$ the homology of $\#^k S^\infty$ is trivial. Note that $S^\infty$ is contractible as well as $S^\infty\setminus\{\mathrm{pt}\}$. Use Mayer-Vietoris.